# How can I batch convert some .jpgs to .pngs

Tags: ubuntu-mate, convert

I would like to convert some .jpgs to a 640x480 size.

I looked through my Ubuntu_Tips.odt file and found this.

```
Convert png to a 640x480 png.
 convert Screenshot_1360x768.png -resize 640x480! 640smaller.png
```

I have 8 of those files in /home/andy/Downloads/.

Is there a way to do a batch convert of those .jpgs files to the smaller file size?

Thanks.

Comment: use a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat your command 8 times? It is probably the better method as you might need to change your command on the current proportions of those files. A command that repeats `convert` without taking that in consideration will not get the expected result.

Instead of convert there is also `mogrify`. It does not require a 2nd filename so this will convert all pngs to 640x480. You can narrow it down by altering the wildcard:

```
mogrify -resize 640x480 *.png
```

(this will overwrite the existing file(s))

If you need to alter proportions you need to add an escaped !:

```
convert -resize 640x480\! {file_old}.png {file_new}.png
```

(this will result in a new file)